# Running LESS server-side vs. client-side

Tags: javascript, css, less

What are the advantages / disadvantages to running the LESS framework client-side vs. server-side? Does page load time take a hit if you run it client-side?

Comment: Dynamic CSS is such a pain to get working cross browser. Do yourself a favour and serve static css instead.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On the server, you have to take more care with your cache control headers and you sacrifice a bit of CPU power.

On the client, it breaks if JS isn't available.

(For your production systems,) do it at build time and just serve up static CSS. That's efficient and reliable.

Comment: Agreeing with Quentin. LESS should never be used in a live environment because of speed issues (and if JS, compatability issues). Just copy the generated css into a static stylesheet and serve that. Only takes 2 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Using ASP.NET MVC 4.0 Bundling you can use:

```
var bundle = new StyleBundle("~/Content/style").Include(
    "~/Content/myStyles.less");
bundle.Transforms.Add(new LessTransform());

bundles.Add(bundle);
```

Everything will be handled very nicely. Caching, Transforming (server-side), bundling and ...

Answer (score 0):

### Client-side:

Advantages:

- Better debugging
- May be easier in development

Disadvantages:

- Slower in terms of bandwidth
- Slower in terms of cpu performance (may affect mobile devices)
- Breaks without JS

### Server-side:

Advantages:

- Faster
- Client JS independent

Disadvantages:

- A little bit more work to implement

### My advise:

Never ever use client side in production. In development it may however be very useful to compile less client side.