# Is this how CSS LESS and SimpLESS work?

Tags: css, less

I do a lot of front end work and was thinking of picking up CSS LESS, but midway through learning it, realized it may not work the way that I thought it would work and might not be able to help me as much. So I think below is how CSS LESS works, could someone who have used it just confirm please?

> CSS LESS works using the SimpLESS compiler and makes the process of
>   initial css coding more easy with programming elements implemented.
>   However, before uploading the css code, it must be converted from the
>   dynamic .less format to the normal .css format and once uploaded to
>   the server, can only act as a static .css file.

Is the above correct? I ask because I work with a lot of wordpress websites and themes that already have the majority of their stylesheet created, and if I have to compile the .less format to .css format and reupload every single time rather than being able to use it as a dynamic pre-loaded library like jQuery, then I might not be able to get as much out of CSS LESS as I previously thought it would benefit me.

Comment: LESS is just a "compiled" CSS format, allowing you to use shorthand. Yes, the browser can only use .css so you wouldn't be able to directly upload the .less file, but you can always keep the .less, make changes, then upload the assembled result.

Comment: Also, as indicated on the LESS homepage, it can run client-side using JavaScript for processing. Check out the gigantic "Download less.js" button.

Comment: As for running it client-side, see this other SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993224/running-less-server-side-vs-client-side

Comment: If you have to support shitty old browsers that run on shitty old OS, like ie8 on windows 7(espically in countries outside the US) then you can use SimplesLESS to compile your less file in to a css file that will be 99% the same as the less file.  Or you can save on client side performance by compiling a .LESS file that won't change

Comment: @JohnB Regardless of the browsers you are supporting you should always present precompiled CSS to a browser. The JavaScript compiler should only be used during development allowing you to edit the LESS file and reload the page rather than recompiling each time (though there are many applications that will track your less files and recompile on the fly)

Comment: @Chao totally agree.  I ws just trying to list examples of why and how you should use those 2 things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both LESS and SASS are technologies designed to aid in the development and maintenance stages of creating CSS files; they work similarly to how Coffee Script is designed to work for javascript. In the end, however, LESS and SASS end up as CSS files just as Coffee Script results in plain old js files.

In any case, there are workflows that automatically handle compilation/save/upload of CSS files to prevent that step from taking extra time and work on your part, but no - browsers do not understand them by default. You can use javascript implementations as comments have mentioned, however.

LESS/SASS have their strengths, but making minor tweaks or customizations of existing themes and styles might not necessarily be one of them. This is not to say that you might not actually get a lot out of the technologies, but that is beyond the scope of your present question and would not even be something I am presently qualified to answer.

Comment: +1 Yes, as I understand it, the main benefit of preprocessors (like LESS and SASS) is to extend features for you as the developer.